# sed command to insert line after a block/paragraph and make changes in file

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, sed

I need to use a `sed` command to insert line after a block/paragraph and make changes in a file. Here is a example of what I want.

Input: `config.cfg.new`

```
backend teatapp_cluster
        option httplog
        mode http
        appsession JSESSIONID len 52 timeout 20m
        errorloc 503 /
        errorloc 504 /
        cookie SERVERID2 insert indirect
        acl rpspath path_sub /s/
        acl clpath path_sub /common/
        #option httpclose
        server portaltest100 l-portaltest100:80 cookie portaltest100 check port 81 inter 2000 rise 3 fall 5 maxconn 150 maxqueue 5 slowstart 15s
        server portaltest200 l-portaltest200:80 cookie portaltest200 check port 81 inter 2000 rise 3 fall 5 maxconn 150 maxqueue 5 slowstart 15s
```

Command (which is not working):

Variables:

```
h="server portaltest300 l-portaltest300:80 cookie portaltest300 check port 81 inter 2000 rise 3 fall 5 maxconn 150 maxqueue 5 slowstart 15s"
cluster="teatapp"

sed -i "/^backend ${cluster}_cluster[ ]*$/, /^[ ]*server.*/ i\ $h " config.cfg.new
```

Desired output:

```
backend teatapp_cluster
        option httplog
        mode http
        appsession JSESSIONID len 52 timeout 20m
        errorloc 503 /
        errorloc 504 /
        cookie SERVERID2 insert indirect
        acl rpspath path_sub /s/
        acl clpath path_sub /common/
        #option httpclose
        server portaltest100 l-portaltest100:80 cookie portaltest100 check port 81 inter 2000 rise 3 fall 5 maxconn 150 maxqueue 5 slowstart 15s
        server portaltest200 l-portaltest200:80 cookie portaltest200 check port 81 inter 2000 rise 3 fall 5 maxconn 150 maxqueue 5 slowstart 15s
        server portaltest300 l-portaltest300:80 cookie portaltest300 check port 81 inter 2000 rise 3 fall 5 maxconn 150 maxqueue 5 slowstart 15s
```

The command:

```
sed -e '/\[Block B\]/{:a;n;/^$/!ba;i\inserted line' -e '}'
```

does what I need. But how can I deal with variable and inserting line to file?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. It is a bit surprising that you've not gotten any answer after 15 hours, but the question is a bit hard to read and understand. You should learn how to indent code; that would make it easier to read.  I think you've under-specified your problem. Presumably, there are multiple `backend` entries similar to the one shown in the config file, with no blank lines between them to help. And you want to insert the new server entry at the end of the relevant `backend` block, before the next block, or before EOF if there is no next block.

Answer (score 3):

This is a moderately tricky problem. I'm not convinced `sed` is the best tool for the job (I'd use Perl; Python would be fine too).  However, here is a `sed` script that seems to do more or less what you want.

```
sed "
/^backend ${cluster}_cluster *$/{
x;s/.*/        ${h}/;x;n
}
/^backend/{
x
s/./&/
t next
x
b
:next
p
s/.*//
x
}
$ {
x
s/./&/
t echo
x
b
:echo
p
}"
```

You have to have a warped sense of humour to produce a script like that — fortunately for you, my sense of humour is twisted beyond belief.

The script has 3 blocks in it.

1. `/^backend ${cluster}_cluster *$/` recognizes the particular backend cluster you are after. The actions on the next line are:

   - `x` swap the pattern and hold space (which was empty),
   - `s///` replace the hold space with the replacement string (line to be inserted),
   - `x` switch the pattern and hold space again, and
   - `n` print the line and moves on to the next cycle.

   Thus, this stashes the data to be written into the hold space.  It could be split onto 4 lines.
2. `/^backend/` recognizes any of the other `backend` lines. The actions are:

   - `x` switch the pattern and hold space;
   - `s/./&/` substitute a character from what was in the hold space with itself;
   - `t` test to see whether it did a substitution (which it will if the hold space is not empty), jumping to label `next` if there was a substitution.
   - If the hold space was empty, then it does:
   - `x` switch the pattern and hold space again and
   - `b` jump to the end of the script (`b`), which prints the line.
   - `:next` is the label.
   - If the hold space was not empty,
   - `p` print its contents,
   - `s///` empty the contents, and
   - `x` swap the hold space and the pattern space once more.

   The line will be printed, but the hold space is empty once more.
3. `$` is the end-of-file pattern. If you reach EOF and the hold space is not empty, it needs to be printed.

   - `x` swap hold and pattern space
   - `s/./&/` test whether there was anything in hold space
   - `t` jump to `echo` label if there was something there
   - `x` swap pattern and hold spaces again
   - `b` jump to end of script
   - `:echo` label
   - `p` print what was in the hold space

That's all there is to.

Three sample data files:

#### config.cfg.new.0

```
backend teatapp_cluster
        option httplog
        mode http
        appsession JSESSIONID len 52 timeout 20m
        errorloc 503 /
        errorloc 504 /
        cookie SERVERID2 insert indirect
        acl rpspath path_sub /s/
        acl clpath path_sub /common/
        #option httpclose
        server portaltest100 l-portaltest100:80 cookie portaltest100 check port 81 inter 2000 rise 3 fall 5 maxconn 150 maxqueue 5 slowstart 15s
        server portaltest200 l-portaltest200:80 cookie portaltest200 check port 81 inter 2000 rise 3 fall 5 maxconn 150 maxqueue 5 slowstart 15s
```

#### config.cfg.new.1

```
backend abcdef_cluster
        option httplog
        cookie SERVERID2 insert indirect
        server abcdeftest100 l-abcdeftest100:80 cookie abcdeftest100 check port 81 inter 2000 rise 3 fall 5 maxconn 150 maxqueue 5 slowstart 15s
        server abcdeftest200 l-abcdeftest200:80 cookie abcdeftest200 check port 81 inter 2000 rise 3 fall 5 maxconn 150 maxqueue 5 slowstart 15s
backend teatapp_cluster
        option httplog
        mode http
        appsession JSESSIONID len 52 timeout 20m
        errorloc 503 /
        errorloc 504 /
        cookie SERVERID2 insert indirect
        acl rpspath path_sub /s/
        acl clpath path_sub /common/
        #option httpclose
        server portaltest100 l-portaltest100:80 cookie portaltest100 check port 81 inter 2000 rise 3 fall 5 maxconn 150 maxqueue 5 slowstart 15s
        server portaltest200 l-portaltest200:80 cookie portaltest200 check port 81 inter 2000 rise 3 fall 5 maxconn 150 maxqueue 5 slowstart 15s
```

#### config.cfg.new.2

```
backend abcdef_cluster
        option httplog
        cookie SERVERID2 insert indirect
        server abcdeftest100 l-abcdeftest100:80 cookie abcdeftest100 check port 81 inter 2000 rise 3 fall 5 maxconn 150 maxqueue 5 slowstart 15s
        server abcdeftest200 l-abcdeftest200:80 cookie abcdeftest200 check port 81 inter 2000 rise 3 fall 5 maxconn 150 maxqueue 5 slowstart 15s
backend teatapp_cluster
        option httplog
        mode http
        appsession JSESSIONID len 52 timeout 20m
        errorloc 503 /
        errorloc 504 /
        cookie SERVERID2 insert indirect
        acl rpspath path_sub /s/
        acl clpath path_sub /common/
        #option httpclose
        server portaltest100 l-portaltest100:80 cookie portaltest100 check port 81 inter 2000 rise 3 fall 5 maxconn 150 maxqueue 5 slowstart 15s
        server portaltest200 l-portaltest200:80 cookie portaltest200 check port 81 inter 2000 rise 3 fall 5 maxconn 150 maxqueue 5 slowstart 15s
backend pqrxyz_cluster
        option httplog
        cookie SERVERID2 insert indirect
        server pqrxyztest100 l-pqrxyztest100:80 cookie pqrxyztest100 check port 81 inter 2000 rise 3 fall 5 maxconn 150 maxqueue 5 slowstart 15s
        server pqrxyztest200 l-pqrxyztest200:80 cookie pqrxyztest200 check port 81 inter 2000 rise 3 fall 5 maxconn 150 maxqueue 5 slowstart 15s
```

Output of sed script for each.

#### Output 0

```
backend teatapp_cluster
        option httplog
        mode http
        appsession JSESSIONID len 52 timeout 20m
        errorloc 503 /
        errorloc 504 /
        cookie SERVERID2 insert indirect
        acl rpspath path_sub /s/
        acl clpath path_sub /common/
        #option httpclose
        server portaltest100 l-portaltest100:80 cookie portaltest100 check port 81 inter 2000 rise 3 fall 5 maxconn 150 maxqueue 5 slowstart 15s
        server portaltest300 l-portaltest300:80 cookie portaltest300 check port 81 inter 2000 rise 3 fall 5 maxconn 150 maxqueue 5 slowstart 15s
        server portaltest300 l-portaltest300:80 cookie portaltest300 check port 81 inter 2000 rise 3 fall 5 maxconn 150 maxqueue 5 slowstart 15s
```

#### Output 1

```
backend abcdef_cluster
        option httplog
        cookie SERVERID2 insert indirect
        server abcdeftest100 l-abcdeftest100:80 cookie abcdeftest100 check port 81 inter 2000 rise 3 fall 5 maxconn 150 maxqueue 5 slowstart 15s
        server abcdeftest200 l-abcdeftest200:80 cookie abcdeftest200 check port 81 inter 2000 rise 3 fall 5 maxconn 150 maxqueue 5 slowstart 15s
backend teatapp_cluster
        option httplog
        mode http
        appsession JSESSIONID len 52 timeout 20m
        errorloc 503 /
        errorloc 504 /
        cookie SERVERID2 insert indirect
        acl rpspath path_sub /s/
        acl clpath path_sub /common/
        #option httpclose
        server portaltest100 l-portaltest100:80 cookie portaltest100 check port 81 inter 2000 rise 3 fall 5 maxconn 150 maxqueue 5 slowstart 15s
        server portaltest300 l-portaltest300:80 cookie portaltest300 check port 81 inter 2000 rise 3 fall 5 maxconn 150 maxqueue 5 slowstart 15s
        server portaltest300 l-portaltest300:80 cookie portaltest300 check port 81 inter 2000 rise 3 fall 5 maxconn 150 maxqueue 5 slowstart 15s
```

#### Output 2

```
backend abcdef_cluster
        option httplog
        cookie SERVERID2 insert indirect
        server abcdeftest100 l-abcdeftest100:80 cookie abcdeftest100 check port 81 inter 2000 rise 3 fall 5 maxconn 150 maxqueue 5 slowstart 15s
        server abcdeftest200 l-abcdeftest200:80 cookie abcdeftest200 check port 81 inter 2000 rise 3 fall 5 maxconn 150 maxqueue 5 slowstart 15s
backend teatapp_cluster
        option httplog
        mode http
        appsession JSESSIONID len 52 timeout 20m
        errorloc 503 /
        errorloc 504 /
        cookie SERVERID2 insert indirect
        acl rpspath path_sub /s/
        acl clpath path_sub /common/
        #option httpclose
        server portaltest100 l-portaltest100:80 cookie portaltest100 check port 81 inter 2000 rise 3 fall 5 maxconn 150 maxqueue 5 slowstart 15s
        server portaltest200 l-portaltest200:80 cookie portaltest200 check port 81 inter 2000 rise 3 fall 5 maxconn 150 maxqueue 5 slowstart 15s
        server portaltest300 l-portaltest300:80 cookie portaltest300 check port 81 inter 2000 rise 3 fall 5 maxconn 150 maxqueue 5 slowstart 15s
backend pqrxyz_cluster
        option httplog
        cookie SERVERID2 insert indirect
        server pqrxyztest100 l-pqrxyztest100:80 cookie pqrxyztest100 check port 81 inter 2000 rise 3 fall 5 maxconn 150 maxqueue 5 slowstart 15s
        server pqrxyztest200 l-pqrxyztest200:80 cookie pqrxyztest200 check port 81 inter 2000 rise 3 fall 5 maxconn 150 maxqueue 5 slowstart 15s
```

I make no guarantees whatsoever that there isn't a far simpler `sed` script that can do the job. If the problem doesn't involve multiple `backend` entries in the config file, it becomes trivial, for example (add the new line at the end).

Incidentally, your `i\` notation didn't work because:

1. You must have a newline after the `i\` and each line to be inserted except the last must end in a backslash.
2. Because you had to use double quotes around the script (to get the cluster prefix and new line into the script), you need to use doubled-up backslashes — so you needed to write:

   ```
   sed -e "/pattern/i\\
   replacement line 1\\
   replacement line 2" ...
   ```

Comment: There is an explanation in the numbered list headed by 'the script has 3 sections in it'.  Granted, it is a little terse (I'll make it a little more verbose) but there is an explanation. It does assume you've read the man page for `sed` and know that there is a pattern space (which the current line is read into each time a line is read) and the hold space (a second lot of storage for a line or lines).

Answer (score 0):

For comparison, here is an awk solution:

```
#! /bin/bash

h="server portaltest300 l-portaltest300:80 cookie portaltest300 check port 81 inter 2000 rise 3 fall 5 maxconn 150 maxqueue 5 slowstart 15s"
cluster="teatapp"

mv config.cfg.new config.cfg.new.bak 
awk -vcls="$cluster" -vh="$h" -f i.awk config.cfg.new.bak > config.cfg.new
```

where `i.awk` is:

```
/^backend/ {
    if (f) print "        "h
    f=0
}
$0 ~ ("^backend "cls"_cluster") {
    f=1
}
{print}
```